# IBM Connections 4.0 iWidget title attribute not working

Tags: ibm-connections

I have added a new tab in my profile page of IBM Connections 4.0 by registering it in widgets-config.xml file the tab is successfully added and is working fine but the problem is i want to give some custom name to the tab like "Hello World" i tried adding title attribute to the iWidget xml file but its not working, the server is always picking the defId used in the widgets-config.xml as tab name instead of the title attribute,i also tried adding the name in widgets-config.xml file itself but the space is causing the problem. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.below is how the iWidget xml file looks like.

```
<iw:iwidget name="helloWorld" title="Hello World" xmlns:iw="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/iWidget"
  iScope="HelloWorldWidgetClass" supportedModes="view">
  <iw:resource uri="helloworld.js" />            
  <iw:content mode="view">
    <![CDATA[
        <div id="frameHolder" style="width:678px;height:606px;">
              <iframe id="testFrame" style="width:inherit;height:inherit;border:none;"></iframe> 
        </div>
    ]]>
 </iw:content>
```

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

The wording used in [iWidgets 2.1 spec document](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/mashups/developer/iwidget-spec-v2.1.pdf) suggests that the use of the title attribute is not mandatory by the container:

> title: This attribute suggests a title that could be used in any decoration (e.g. titlebar) around the iWidget. This item can be set in both the iWidget definition and the microformat placing an iWidget instance on a page.

I suggest opening an IBM Connections PMR to bring this issue to the attention of the development team.

Answer (score 0):

In Connections, the title and descriptions for iwidget are both defined in widget-config.xml by "defId" and "description". You could add NLV support for these 2 string by add "Customizing product strings" to Connections.

Here is a brief steps to do that:

1. in widget-config.xml
2. in LotusConnections-config.xml
3. put your strings file in 
   /strings/com.xxx.myWidget.properties
   /strings/com.xxx.myWidget_en.properties
   ...
   /strings/com.xxx.myWidget_zh.properties
4. in each of the property file:
   myWidget=My widget title
   myWidget.desc=My widget description

The detailed steps could be found in Connections product document, but the idea is same, to provide customize string support for 3rd party iwidget.